# WPF MVVM open new window and pass ID to it

Tags: wpf, mvvm

In my application I have a listview in one of my windows. I want to open a new window when I select an item from this listview and show details about it. What is the best approach to open a new window with mvvm and pass a value(id) to it so that I can get the desired information from my database?

Comment: I'd consider getting the desired information from your database, using it to populate a model, then passing this model to your new window.

Comment: How can I pass the model to my new window?

Comment: Give your window class a `Model` property, then: `var wind = new MyWindow() { Model = myModel };`

Comment: How about you post your code